# Joint and marginal distributions and expectations (Is my proof right?)

Tags: integration, conditional-probability

**1. Please look this following proof first:**
[image]

**2. I want to proof the conditional case, and the proof process is following.**

[image]

**3. I want somebody to help to check whether my proof is right? Thanks**

Comment: prob, college calc or stat homework, right?

Comment: Yes, it is my homework.

Comment: well, have a good time doing your homework over break.

Comment: Do you think my proof is right?

Comment: I have no idea, haven't gotten that far yet.